# why nanoscrollbar does not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, nanoscroller

I added nanoscrollbar to my code, it has effect but the scroll not seen. I think scroll's div has class pane but its not even seen in DOM while inspecting. What is missing?
And I added below link nano.css, jquery, nano.js.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$(".nano").nanoScroller();});</script>

<body>
<div id="about" class="nano">
    <div class="nano-content">
         This is the content box and it should be scrolling but it is not!! =/.  
        This is the content box and it should be scrolling but it is not!! =/.  This is the content box and it should be scrolling but it is not!! =/.  This is the content box and it should be scrolling but it is not!! =/.  This is the content box and it should be scrolling but it is  not!! =/.  
    </div> 
</div>        
</body>
```

Comment: Please, show your browser console.

Comment: I see that and it say jQuery and $ not deifined